# Google account history shows up at the same hour

Tags: google, history

Why is all the app activity on Google account history showing up at the same hour?

Activity from a Samsung Galaxy A21 shows, for example, Gallery, Messages, social media apps, Weather app, and whatever else at 3:57 PM.

Why? And is there anything I can do? Thank you.